# Handling data between pages

Tags: flutter

Suppose I have a multipage app with a home page and several very similar child pages.  Each of those child pages will have text input that generate similar data.  I want to display each of these pieces of data from the home page.

EDIT:  In the code below, we can assume "BottomHalf" is the second page.

I am having trouble accessing the textcontroller of the child pages on the home page.

EDIT:  Lets assume all I want to do is display the _counter from _MyHomePageState in BottomHalf.

I assumed it would be as simple as calling the object.variable but I guess not. 
 In my search for an answer I've come across Streams, this sounds promising but I'm not sure if thats too complicated for this scenario.  I've also come across Listenables, I can't seem to figure these out.

The code as shown will not update the variable bottomCounterView.

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 150),
            BottomHalf(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BottomHalf extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _BottomHalfState createState() => _BottomHalfState();
}

class _BottomHalfState extends State<BottomHalf> {
  var bottomCounterView;


  bottomCounter() async {
    setState(() => bottomCounterView = _MyHomePageState()._counter);
    print('$bottomCounterView');
    print('${_MyHomePageState()._counter}');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text('I am showing this number from a separate widget'),
        Text('${bottomCounter()}'),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO! In general you should avoid things like "Hello" or "I'm a beginner" or everything similar here. This "adds noise" to the content of your question and therefore SO dislike it

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.  I'll leave that out next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the good information from @YauhenSampir, that got me started and I found these three tutorials on Streams/BLoC/Broadcast.  Perfect fit:

Ep.1 - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h3TEEGceYsU

Ep.2 - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QnAoEV5UraI

Ep.3 - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qitQmyDICXc

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to see some samples with streams and reactive programming.
Please, check few links:

1. [Reactive programming in flutter](https://www.didierboelens.com/2018/12/reactive-programming---streams---bloc---practical-use-cases/)
2. [More about reactive programming in flutter](https://www.didierboelens.com/2018/08/reactive-programming---streams---bloc/)
3. [Real example how it works](https://github.com/boeledi/Streams-Block-Reactive-Programming-in-Flutter) but do not forget to get API key for example

Updated:
As I understand, you need something like this

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CounterPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final StreamController<int> _streamController = StreamController<int>();

  CounterPage() {
    _streamController.stream.listen(onData);
  }

  @override
  _CounterPageState createState() => _CounterPageState();

  void onData(int event) {
    print(event);
  }
}

class _CounterPageState extends State<CounterPage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    widget._streamController.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Stream version of the Counter App')),
      body: Center(
        child: StreamBuilder<int>(
            stream: widget._streamController.stream,
            initialData: _counter,
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<int> snapshot) {
              return Text('You hit me: ${snapshot.data} times');
            }),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {
          widget._streamController.sink.add(++_counter);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But I recon, this is quite bad practice. Please, check blocs(links above) where logic with streams and data incapsulated and where dispose can be managed easier.

Comment: This is really great stuff for Streams.  However, I am trying to ask a more basic question.  I understand the class().method.variable structure, but when the information I want is inside the state class of a page I can't reach it.  If I have a textfield inside of a state class, how do I access the data which is input from another page?

Comment: Answer updated. Please check, I believe this is what you need, code can have some mistakes.

Comment: I've updated the original question to possibly be more clear.  I feel this is such a fundamental question, I cannot believe I have beat this to death for two days.  I just want to show a variable from one widget in another.  Can you also explain why you state it is bad practice?  I do appreciate the help, this is my first attempt at learning a programming language beyond Fortran and Assembly.

Comment: Using the info above I found these three tutorials, perfect fit!